# I am trying to plot data with errorbars, I am constructing an array for the errors, but I can get no errorbars in the plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

> Hi all,
> here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
columns = [[]] * 3
with open('output_stat_ffoe1.txt','r') as token:
    for line in token:
        for field, value in enumerate(line.split()):
             columns[field].append(value)
print(columns[0])
lst=columns[0]
import operator
get1 = operator.itemgetter(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24 ,27 )
datax = np.array(get1(lst)).astype(float)
get2 = operator.itemgetter(1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25 ,28 )
datay = np.array(get2(lst)).astype(float)
get3 = operator.itemgetter(2, 5, 8, 11,14, 17,20, 23, 26 ,29 )
errory = get3(lst)
y_error = np.array(errory).astype(float)
print(np.size(y_error))
print(np.size(datay))
print(y_error)
#fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
plt.errorbar(datax, datay, yerr=y_error, capsize=3, fmt="b--o", ecolor = "black")
#plt.errorbar(datax, datay, yerr=errory, fmt="o")
#plt.errorbar(datax, datay, yerr=errory, capsize=3, fmt="r--o", ecolor = "black")
```

Then the output plot contains no errorbars. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hljGt.png)

Comment: Could you add some test data? E.g. via the output of `print(list(y_error))`. If the errors are very small, the error bars won't be visible.

Comment: To not get your columns mixed while reading the file, you need to initialize `columns = [[],[],[])`. Initializing with `columns = [[]] * 3` makes Python share the memory. It would be a lot easier to read the file via `columns = np.loadtxt('output_stat_ffoe1.txt')`, which would also store the numbers as floats.

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#columns = [[]] * 3
columns = ([],[],[])
with open('output_stat_ffoe1.txt','r') as token:
    for line in token:
        for field, value in enumerate(line.split()):
             columns[field].append(value)
print(columns[0])
print(columns[1])
print(columns[2])
lst1=columns[0]
lst2=columns[1]
lsterror=columns[2]
datax = np.array(lst1).astype(float)
datay = np.array(lst2).astype(float)
errory = np.array(lsterror).astype(float) plt.errorbar(datax, datay, errory, capsize=3, fmt="b--o", ecolor = "black")

Comment: The code still produced a plot with no errorbars, so I modified the last line: plt.errorbar(datax, datay, errory, 0.0, 'none'). Now it is much better, with no other constructions hiding the bars. Thanks for your suggestions.